# clustering in python without number of clusters or threshold

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

Is it possible to do clustering without providing any input apart from the data? The clustering method/algorithm should decide from the data on how many logical groups the data can be divided, even it doesn't require me to input the threshold eucledian distance on which the clusters are built, this also needs to be learned from the data.

Could you please suggest me what is closest solution for my problem?

Comment: There are clustering algorithms which can decide number of clusters for you (e.g. genetic clustering). But if you are a beginner, you can start with hierarchical clustering, which clusters data into nested clusters. Afterward, you can prune the clusters to keep only big meaningful ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not code your algorithm to create a list of clusters ranging from size 1 to n (which could be defined in a config file so that you can avoid hard coding and just fix it once).

Once that is done, compute the clusters of size 1 to n. Choose the value which gives you the smallest Mean Square Error.

This would require some additional work by your machine to determine the optimal number of logical groups the data can be divided (bounded between 1 and n).

Answer (score 1):

Clustering is an explorative technique.

This means it *must* always be able to produce different results, as desired by the user. **Having many parameters is a feature**. It means the method can be adapted easily to very different data, and to user preferences.

There will never be a generally useful parameter-free technique. At best, some parameters will have default values or heuristics (such as Euclidean distance, such as standardizing the input prior to clusterings such as the gap statistic for choosing k) that may give a reasonable *first try* in 80% of cases. But after that first try, you'll need to understand the data, and try other parameters to learn more about your data.

Methods that claim to be "parameter free" usually just have some hidden parameters set so it works on the few toy example it was demonstrated on.